# WCF WebApi HttpResponseException Issue

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I am trying to throw an `HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)` and I am getting the following error

> The response message returned by the Response property of this exception should be immediately returned to the client.  No further handling of the request message is required.

I have removed all of the code in my method and I am just throwing the exception like this

```
[WebGet]
public MyData Get()
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

If I change my method to return a `HttpResponseMessage` I can get it to work correctly, however it does not solve the issue and I am unable to get my authentication operation handler  to work without being able to throw a `HttpResponseException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [`WebFaultException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989925.aspx) for returning HTTP Status codes in WCF...

```cs
throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

Comment: that worked great but for some reason if I use a status code of unauthorized I still get a 404?

Comment: @Stuart do you have any operation/message handler which might be causing the 404?

Comment: @AntonyScott the only handler I have is an authorization handler that I have copied from a Haack post. It only throws unauthorized exceptions.

Comment: i used that and had the same issues, i changed to using a message handler and found that works much better

Comment: Do you know of an example of using the message handler for authorization

Comment: I have written one myself. I will be writing a blog article about it tomorrow (maybe later today), I'll post a link when I've written it.

Comment: I've been migrating my project to ASP.NET Web Api over the last few days. The task for Monday (when I return to work) is to get authentication working. I suspect this will turn into a non-issue as I'm hoping I can just use the authentication code built in to ASP.NET :)

Comment: I am now moving over to ASP.NET Web Api as well, so this should now be a breeze. Thanks for your help @AntonyScott. Now just need to be patient until the RTM of MVC4